# Audio in webview continues to play in background

Tags: android, audio, webview

I have a webview with an audio player. If I start the audio and press back to return to the previous activity, the audio still keeps playing in background. This problem only occurs when the API is lower than 11.

My code:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
           webView.onPause();
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        }
}
```

I also tried

```
webView.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

And

```
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.destroy();
```

But it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

A simple hack that worked for me is

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.location=document.location");
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes...none of the onPause methods would work. This is the only fix that disabled the audio playing from my HTML5 Webview when changing fragments in my viewpager. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem fro API > 11

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(webView != null) {
        webView.onPause();
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (webView != null) {
        webView.onResume();
    }
}
```

but for lower versions (in your case) you need to call `onPause` and `onResume` as follows

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
          webview.onPause();
        } else {
    try {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                            .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        ...
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        ...
    } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
        ...
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        ...
    }
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onPause();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
          webview.onResume();
        } else {
    try {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onResume", (Class[]) null)
                            .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        ...
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        ...
    } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
        ...
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        ...
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work, the audio still continues to play in background.